# JS phone number validation - matching strings

Tags: javascript, string, validation, indexof

All I need to do is checking if the input includes any value of the given array. For some reason it returns always true;

```
document.querySelector('#phonenumber').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    let alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    let target = e.target.value;
    let splittedTarget = target.split('');

    console.log(splittedTarget, alphabet)

    if (alphabet.indexOf(splittedTarget) > -1) {
      alert('there is not');
    } else {
      alert('there is');
    }
});
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/et5avosu/

Comment: why not use regex for validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.some()` on your input characters:

```
const alphaInInput = !splittedTarget.some(elem => alphabet.indexOf(elem) > -1);
```

`alphaInInput` will be a `boolean`. If your input contains a character from the `alphabet` string then it will be `true`, if it doesn't then it will be `false`.

See working example below:

```js
document.querySelector('#phonenumber').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    let alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; // Remove .split() (no need for array)
    let target = e.target.value;
    let splittedTarget = target.split('');
  
    const alphaInInput = splittedTarget.some(elem => alphabet.indexOf(elem) > -1);
   
    // console.log(splittedTarget, alphabet)
    if (!alphaInInput) {
      alert('there is not');
    } else {
      alert('there is');
    }
  });
```

```html
<input id="phonenumber" />
```

***Or you can use `regex`*** by using the following pattern `/[A-Za-z]/g`, and then using `.test()` to see whether your input matches the pattern.

**Note**: The  `/[A-Za-z]/g` tests for characters from A to Z and a to z, ie, what your Alphabet string contains:

```js
document.querySelector('#phonenumber').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    let inputStr = e.target.value;
    let regex = /[A-Za-z]/g;
    let alphaInInput = regex.test(inputStr);
   
    if (!alphaInInput) {
      alert('there is not');
    } else {
      alert('there is');
    }
  });
```

```html
<input id="phonenumber" />
```

Comment: @AlessioChiffi No worries, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

`Array<String>.indexOf(Array)` is always `-1`, because the list of `String`s does not contain an `Array`. You need to use some other method to validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, I tested and it worked

```
 document.querySelector('#phonenumber').addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    let alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    let target = e.target.value;
    let splittedTarget = target.split('');

    if(splittedTarget.every(r => alphabet.indexOf(r) < 0)){
        alert('only numbers');
    } else {
          alert('there is letter');
    }
  });
```